# I need to get the data from double values without having decimal places

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, double, type-conversion

I have a `double` variable as shown Below

```
double var1 = 0;
```

And
    I Have a `Value = 123.25`.

For Example `var1 += Math.Round(123.25)`, I am getting 123.0

So I need to get the Data Like as shown Below?

Output should be = 123

Comment: What is `var1`? How are you using it when it produces the values with .0 at the end?

Answer (score 3):

The problem isn't in the data - it's in the string conversion. There's no difference for a `double` between 123.0 and 123... they're *exactly* the same values, with the same bits.

So instead of focusing on the `double` value itself, you should look at how you're using it - which you haven't told us about. For example, you might just want to change the format pattern you're using.

Comment: Could you Please Provide me with the code, Because am a Fresher

Comment: @Subbu: No, we can't give you the code - you haven't shown us how you're using the value (i.e. where you're seeing 123.0)... besides, the aim is for you to *learn* - so you should look at your code and use the information provided in the answers to see if you can fix it for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

How about using:

```
(int)var1
```

Wherever you need to show its value?

Comment: @Subbu: "It's not working" is *never* a good response. You should *always* provide more information.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question. If you only want the integer value why not have the Math.Round() result be assigned to a type int? That would get you what you want.

```
int x = (int)Math.Round(123.25);
```

I cannot understand the reason you don't like the .0 at the end? If you print the variable holding 123.0 it shows up as 123. I can only see 123.0 when using debugger.
How are you using the value? If you could tell us then we could find a better solution if none of the ones provided are of use to you.

Answer (score 0):

```
int someOtherInt = Convert.ToInt32(var1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your getting confused with the types. You don't want to use `double` in this situation by the sounds of it. Instead, use `int`.

```
int var1 = 0;
int var2 = (int)123.25;
int output = var1 + var2;
```

`output` in this case is 123. Cast to `int` removes the need for `Math.Round`.

Comment: Shouldn't `output` be 123 here?

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly recommend that you read this: http://www.whathaveyoutried.com

If you follow the suggestions in that article, you will be able to get help in solving your problem in no time.